# Is it guaranteed that subscription for response is established before request is processed in temp-topic based request/response scheme?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websocket, activemq-classic, stomp

I would like to implement an request/response pattern in the following parts:

- **Server:** Springboot with ActiveMQ
- **Client:** JavaScript with stompjs over websocket

I want a behaviour like an http request.

Send a Request, get a corresponding Response.

I try to do this with temporary channels
I send 3 Messages

The steps are:

1. SUBSCRIBE to a temprorary channel

   ```
   SUBSCRIBE
   id:mysub
   destination:/temp-queue/example
   ```
2. SEND the request and include a reply-to header with the subscribed channel of Step 1

   ```
   destination:/queue/PO.REQUEST
   reply-to:/temp-queue/example
   ```
3. Get the Response Message from the Server

   ```
   MESSAGE
   subscription:foo
   reply-to:/queue/temp.default.23.example
   destination:/queue/PO.REQUEST
   reply-to:/temp-queue/example
   ```

But now (As Client send messages asynchronous) im not sure if Step 1 is complete on server, and so server is ready to send Response to the queue when the Request of Step 2 arrives at the server.

Is it possible that server finishes Step 2 before finishing Step 1, and so sends the response to nowhere? Or does ActiveMQ ensures that the received messages 1 and 2 from the client are processed and finished in the correct order?

Can any race condition between message 1 and 2 happen?

Thank you very much!

Comment: ActiveMQ Apollo is deprecated software and is no longer supported, so you probably won't find much help

Comment: I do not use Apollo, i use full ActiveMQ, which also has such Temp Queues.

Comment: I'd recommend removing the references to Apollo from the post and clarifying things a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any STOMP frame that your client sends can be sent with a receipt request that makes the processing of that frame synchronous.  So if you want to ensure that a subscribe is complete before doing the send, then attach a [receipt-id](http://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#Header_receipt) to the subscribe frame and wait for the [spec mandated RECEIPT](http://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#RECEIPT) frame before going on to do the send, this ensures that your subscription is setup prior to any other processing.